# Get Facebook user profil link with hello.js

Tags: facebook, profile, hello.js

I'm using hello.js to login and get user information for several social networks and it works.
I now need to get the facebook users profile link, so I asked for the permission(user_link) for my FB app and got it, so now when I log with the app I'm warned that the app will have access to my profile url.
However I don't know how to get this information with hello.js, all I have in the response is :

```
first_name: "Jerome"
id: "..."
last_name: "..."
name: "..."
picture: "https://graph.facebook.com/.../picture"
thumbnail: "https://graph.facebook.com/.../picture"
```

this is a part of my code :

```
var socialnetwork = facebook;
var socialscopes = basic_profile;
hello(socialnetwork).login({scope: socialscopes},function() {

return hello(socialnetwork).api('me').then(function(r) {
console.log(r);
}
```

A clue ? THX !!!

Comment: Ask for the link field

Comment: Presumably just simply `.api('me?fields=link')`

Comment: Ok thx guy, yes I had to add link in me fields but also ask for user_link scope when loggin. Now it works, THX again !